# How to update items in CrudPanel

Tags: vaadin, crud, updates

In a CrudPanel I have the need to update some items (not through the CRUD dialog). Something like this:

```
    @Transactional
    ...
 
      instance.setSomeAttribute(newValue);
      return savedInstance = instanceRepository.save(instance);
```

Calling refreshAll on the dataProvider after the update produces the warning `Got an RPC for non-existent node: xxxx`. Also I guess it is a little expensive to refresh all items if just one changed.

Calling the specific refresh item, on the other side, `refreshItem(instance)`, gives `Object of class [...MenuItem] with identifier [xxxx]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`

I also tried to pass `newInstance` to refreshItem, same result.

Can somebody indicate how to proceed?

Comment: How is equals and hashcode of the object instance implemented?

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks, you hit the point! I see that the version field (managed by JPA) was part of equals (and obviously hash code too). Once removed the problem disappears. So the problem is sorted out. Honestly I do not understand why the version was included in the equals/hash code test.

Comment: Great! that it works. If you don't mind I will add this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `equals` and `hashCode` that they don't contain fields that may have changed when you call `refreshItem`.